# Having issues with Windows 10/11 running dualbooted Zorin (Ubuntu Fork)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-11, regedit, dualboot

I'm having issues getting windows to run in AHCI mode. When I switch my bios into AHCI, windows bluescreens, as expected- but RegEdit isn't saving my changes to storahci and iaStorV to allow windows to boot from AHCI. I have tried to contact microsoft/windows support with no luck, and I am pretty much stuck. I am aware this isn't completely a windows question, but this question was removed from askUbuntu and I am posting this on the offchance that anyone here has had this same issue and can give me any more information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I suggest you try the methods that come up in a simple Google search, prioritizing the newer entries (some old ways no longer work). Ultimately, if you can't do it for the current installation, then you'll have to reinstall Windows with the firmware set to AHCI.

Comment: I have solved this issue.  Dead simple.